# Convert variable names into strings and use the strings inside a loop

Tags: r

I’m trying to convert variable names into strings. In particular, I would like to retrieve names of raster layers and use them inside a loop.

To do this, I used the `deparse` and `substitute` functions. However, I obtain the following error message:

`Error in parse(text = layer_names[i]) : <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input 1: new("RasterStack", filename = "", layers = list(new("RasterLayer", ^`

Here a simple reproducible example of my problem:

```
source("G:/Downloads/Test.R")
layer_list <- test(1000)
```

```
test <- function(resolution){
  
  ## Create RasterStack objects
  r <- raster(xmn= 0, ymn= 0, xmx = 100000, ymx = 100000, resolution = resolution, crs = '+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs ')
  r <- setValues(r, sample(x = 0:1, size = ncell(r), replace = T))
  
  environmental_layers_scenario_1 <- stack(list(r, r, r))
  environmental_layers_scenario_2 <- stack(list(r, r, r))
  environmental_layers_scenario_3 <- stack(list(r, r, r))
  
  ## Retrieve all names of the raster layers
  layer_names <- c(deparse(substitute(environmental_layers_scenario_1)),
                   deparse(substitute(environmental_layers_scenario_2)),
                   deparse(substitute(environmental_layers_scenario_3)))
  ## print(layer_names)

  ## Loop over the raster layers
  raster_list <- list()
  for(i in 1:length(layer_names)){

    raster_list[[i]] <- eval(parse(text = layer_names[i]))
  }
  
  return(raster_list)
  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to run your code with deparse1 instead of deparse :

```
library(raster)

test <- function(resolution){
  
  ## Create RasterStack objects
  r <- raster(xmn= 0, ymn= 0, xmx = 100000, ymx = 100000, resolution = resolution, crs = '+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs ')
  r <- setValues(r, sample(x = 0:1, size = ncell(r), replace = T))
  
  environmental_layers_scenario_1 <- stack(list(r, r, r))
  environmental_layers_scenario_2 <- stack(list(r, r, r))
  environmental_layers_scenario_3 <- stack(list(r, r, r))
  
  ## Retrieve all names of the raster layers
  layer_names <- c(deparse1(substitute(environmental_layers_scenario_1)),
                   deparse1(substitute(environmental_layers_scenario_2)),
                   deparse1(substitute(environmental_layers_scenario_3)))
  print(layer_names)
  
  ## print(layer_names)

  ## Loop over the raster layers
  raster_list <- list()
  for(i in 1:length(layer_names)){
    print(i)
    print(layer_names[i])
    raster_list[[i]] <- eval(parse(text = layer_names[i]))
  }
 
  return(raster_list)
}

layer_list <- test(1000)

layer_list
[[1]]
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 100, 100, 10000, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 1e+05, 0, 1e+05  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
names      : layer.1, layer.2, layer.3 
min values :       0,       0,       0 
max values :       1,       1,       1 


[[2]]
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 100, 100, 10000, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 1e+05, 0, 1e+05  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
names      : layer.1, layer.2, layer.3 
min values :       0,       0,       0 
max values :       1,       1,       1 


[[3]]
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 100, 100, 10000, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 1e+05, 0, 1e+05  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
names      : layer.1, layer.2, layer.3 
min values :       0,       0,       0 
max values :       1,       1,       1
```